# Find thread consuming CPU time

Tags: android

I am testing an android application and I see that a downloader service is running continuously in the app. The CPU utilzation of the app is high.

How do I identify the thread that is causing the problem and how much time it takes.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK provides many tools for debugging. I suggest you to take a look at [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) and the [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) for profiling.